# jQuery input value div id and change color

Tags: jquery, html, css

How can I change the color by id with JQuery?
can you help me?

Sample:

Can we do this with jQuery?

Sample:

```css
div {
    width:20%;
    height:50px;
    background:red;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    margin: 10px;
    }
```

```html
<div id="box1">BOX1</div>
        <div id="box2">BOX2</div>
        <div id="box3">BOX3</div>
        <div id="box4">BOX4</div>
        <div id="box5">BOX5</div>
        
        <table><tr><td>
        <select class="selectColor" name="option">
      <option value="1">BLUE</option>
      <option value="2">BLACK</option>
      <option value="3">YELLOW</option>
    </select>
        <input type="text" name="cc" placeholder="Div ID"/><br/>
        <input type="button" onClick="colorPin()" value="CHANGE"/>
        
        </td></tr></table>
```

div color change

Comment: Of course you can do that with jQuery. What have you tried so far and why has it failed?

Comment: Please include the JS code you have tried, along with any errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this code:

```
function colorPin(){
  var divid = $("[name=cc]").val()
  var color = $(".selectColor option:selected").text()
  $("#" + divid).css("background",color)
}
```

This will take the selected color and apply it to a div with the input you typed in the input.

**Demo**

```js
function colorPin(){
  var divid = $("[name=cc]").val()
  var color = $(".selectColor option:selected").text()
  $("#" + divid).css("background",color)
}
```

```css
div {
  width: 20%;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="box1">BOX1</div>
<div id="box2">BOX2</div>
<div id="box3">BOX3</div>
<div id="box4">BOX4</div>
<div id="box5">BOX5</div>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <select class="selectColor" name="option">
      <option value="1">BLUE</option>
      <option value="2">BLACK</option>
      <option value="3">YELLOW</option>
    </select>
      <input type="text" name="cc" placeholder="Div ID" /><br/>
      <input type="button" onClick="colorPin()" value="CHANGE" />

    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```